# angular expression binding with condition

Tags: angularjs

```
value="{{Temp.r1c2t != SS ? '100' : '250'}}"
```

This code will worked fine.
When am getting value from database it ll show error.

My code here

```
value="{{Temp.r1c2t != SS ? {{Temp.SSFareAmount}} : {{Temp.SFareAmount}}}}"
```

Comment: `value="{{Temp.r1c2t != SS ? {{Temp.SSFareAmount}} : {{Temp.SFareAmount}}}}"` should be `value="{{Temp.r1c2t != SS ? Temp.SSFareAmount : Temp.SFareAmount}}"` because you are already evaluating it as expression in `{{}}` . so u don`t need it again

Comment: value="{{Temp.r1c2t != SS ? Temp.SSFareAmount : Temp.SFareAmount}}" here  Temp.r1c2t value is SS and SH but  both condition i got Temp.SSFareAmount only.  here i need like this SS - Temp.SSFareAmount and SH - Temp.SFareAmount

Answer (score 0):

Have to use with out curly braces.

Like Below

```
value="{{Temp.r1c2t != SS ? Temp.SSFareAmount : Temp.SFareAmount}}"
```

answer mentioned in comments also.

Comment: value="{{SS != SS ? Temp.SSFareAmount : Temp.SFareAmount}}" It ll getTemp.SSFareAmount  and  SS != SH it ll getTemp.SFareAmount

Comment: Can you share controller code and Temp scope object?.

Answer (score 0):

the {{}} are called [interpolation bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) and they are only needed once per expression.

```
value="{{Temp.r1c2t != SS ? Temp.SSFareAmount : Temp.SFareAmount}}"
```

but it would probably be better to access this as an object like:

```
value={{temp.glue[temp.r1c2t]}}
```

where glue is in the controller:

```
vm.glue = {
    "SS": vm.SSFareAmount,
    "SF": vm.SSFareAmount
}
```

a quick [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8hO9psSxbeGObtizXjRj?p=preview) and you can see that it works just fine.